# How to parallelize a Flink job with Guava cache?

Tags: caching, parallel-processing, guava, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have written a Flink job which uses Guava cache. The cache object is created and used in a run() function called in the main() function.

It is something like :

```
main() {
   run(some,params)
}

run() {
   //create and use Guava cache object here
}
```

If I run this Flink job, with some level of parallelism, will all of the parallel tasks, use the same cache object? If not, how can I make them all use a single cache?

The cache is used inside a process() function for a stream. So it's like

```
incoming_stream.process(new ProcessFunction() { //Use Guava Cache here })
```

You can think of my use case as of cache based deduping, so I want all of the parallel tasks to refer to a single cache object

Comment: From what you have shown there I can't see any problems. You'll get into trouble when you start using your guava cache within the flink-operators (map, fold, filter, etc.). In this case you should use the flink state or the broadcasted state depending on what you want to do. Maybe you can explain your usecase a little more detailed

Comment: The cache is used inside a process() function for a stream. So it's like incoming_stream.process(new ProcessFunction() { //Use Guava Cache here }) . You can think of my use case as of cache based deduping, so I want all of the parallel tasks to refer to a single cache object.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Guava cache with Flink is usually an anti-pattern. Not that it can't be made to work, but there's probably a simpler and more scalable solution.

The standard approach to deduplicating in a thoroughly scalable, performant way with Flink is to partition the stream by some key (using keyBy), and then use keyed state to remember the keys that have been seen. Flink's keyed state is managed by Flink in a way that makes it fault tolerant and rescalable, while keeping it local. Flink's keyed state is a sharded key/value store, with each instance handling all of the events for some portion of the key space. You are guaranteed that for each key, all events for the same key will be processed by the same instance -- which is why this works well for deduplication.

If you need instead that all of the parallel instances have a complete copy of some (possibly evolving) data set, that's what broadcast state is for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also felt that maybe Flink isn't designed to be used like this, but I couldn't come up with an appropriate windowing solution. My use case is not just to deduplicate but collect some values from a category of similar events. This is the windowing solution I need - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328324/flink-session-window-with-oneventtime-trigger

Answer (score 0):

Flink tasks run on multi JVMs or machines,so the issue is how to share objects between JVM.

Normally,you can acquire objects from remote JVM by RPC (via tcp) or rest (via http) call.

Alternatively,you may serialize objects and store them to database like reids,then read from database and deserialize to objects.

In Flink,there is a more graceful way to achive this,you can store objects in [state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/state.html),and [broadcast_state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html) may fit you.

**Broadcast state was introduced to support use cases where some data coming from one stream is required to be broadcasted to all downstream tasks**

Hope this helps.